# Read the cost of outgoing call after the call got disconnected

Tags: android

Is there any possibility to read the cost for the last outgoing call.

I wanna append price into my list view which already has details such as call duration,number,date.

Pls. provide some inputs on this

Comment: Price is network-dependent.

Comment: If you'd like to implement this, you will need to ask your user how much does he pay for a 1 minute call and base the cost on this information.

Answer (score 0):

Only way , you can ask user how much he is paying for a second before launch :) Then you can calculate total price.